# My CSS media query to hide elements isn't working on my HTC ONE M8

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, hide

I'm writing an HTML email and have started coding responsively. The stacking in my email works on my mobile (HTC ONE M8 via the Gmail app) but some of the nav bar elements should hide, and they don't. I originally didn't have the code pointing to phones with increased pixel ratios so assumed that would fix it, but it didn't.

CSS and HTML for the Nav bar below.

Any ideas?

```
@media  only screen and (max-width: 640px),
          only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
            only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
            only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi){


        table[class=hide], td[class=hide], img[class=hide], span[class=hide], br[class=hide] {
            display:none !important;
        }   
 }
```

And the HTML

```
 <table width="740" class="w370" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="39" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/ski/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Ski&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Ski" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Ski</a></td>

        <td width="99" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/snowboard/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Snowboard&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Snowboard" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Snowboard</a></td>

        <td width="51" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/walking/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Walk&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Walk" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Walk</a></td>

        <td width="57" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/climb/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Climb&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Climb" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Climb</a></td>

        <td width="50" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/camping/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Camp&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Camp" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Camp</a></td>

        <td width="51" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/kids/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Kids&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Kids" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Kids</a></td>

        <td width="74" class="hide" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/clothing/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Clothing&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Clothing" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Clothing</a></td>

        <td width="83" class="hide" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/footwear/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Footwear&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Footwear" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Footwear</a></td>    

        <td width="82" class="hide" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/bags/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Luggage&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Luggage" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Luggage</a></td>

        <td width="97" class="hide" bgcolor="#191919" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/electronics/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Electronics&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Electronics" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Electronics</a></td>

        <td width="57" bgcolor="#e41b23" align="center"><a href="http://www.snowandrock.com/all/clearance/fcp-category/home?utm_source=redeye&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Sale&utm_campaign=SNO1194" target="_blank" title="Sale" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px; line-height:30px;font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Sale</a></td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure about the use of @media but css selector for a table with a hide class souldn't be table.hide? 
Same for td, img, etc.

Comment: I've just had the thought that the Gmail app may not support media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, now I´ve read slow your question. Some doubts:

1- Where is your css? I suppose at the same file than your table.

2- Try this media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 720px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3), only screen and (-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3), only screen and (min-resolution: 3dppx)”
```

Some reference: http://blog.denniszhao.com/2014/07/13/css-media-queries-in-2014/

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. I knew .hide was the standard form, but they used the other form in the course I took the other day! I've amended it now.

Comment: Have you any link where I could test your app?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pixel ratio checks, it's deprecated and barely supported by new browsers. You should only use min-resolution

Remove these

```
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
        only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
```

P.s. table[class=hide] actually works but table.hide would be easier forothers to understand and is the standard =)

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the deprecated checks. No joy though,